# Ansible. How to pass argument from local to host machine

Tags: ansible, devops, capistrano

I'm new to Ansible.

Currently I am working with a remote host that use Capistrano as package management agent.
When I run deploy script as follow:

```yaml
    - name: build source
      shell: |
        echo "bundle exec cap branch=staging stg deploy"
      tags:
        - build_source
```

Conifg capistrano is here

```
set :branch, lambda {
  branch = Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask("[cap] Branch or Tag (default `master`): ")
  branch.empty? ? "master" : branch
}
```

Therefore, the Ansible script will be stuck at *ask* step.
I wonder if there is any way to passing argument from an Ansible on local to capistrano on host machine

Many thanks in advance

Comment: See the [`expect` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html).

Comment: Or if that's the only question it asks, you may get away using [`args: {"stdin": "my-branch-name\n"}`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-stdin)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
I was looking for expect module as @Zeitounator suggested